# Kotlinx Serialization: How to circumvent reified typeargs for deserialization?

Tags: json, kotlin, generics, kotlinx.serialization, kotlin-reified-type-parameters

Actually, the main problem is still that there are no reified typeargs for classes in Kotlin. But here is why this bothers me in this specific case:

Suppose you have a wrapper class `Wrapper` that takes in a string `content` and a class* `type` and can output an object of class `type` retrieved by parsing `content` as JSON by demand by calling the function `getObj()`:

```kotlin
class Wrapper<T>(private val content: String, /*private val type: KClass<*>*/) {
    fun getObj(): T {
        // ?
    }
}
```

And I want to use kotlinx.serialization. Now, you might have noticed how I put an asterisk after "class" before. Here's the reason: Yes, `Wrapper` has to take the target class in *some* way, but how? Should it be just the typearg (won't work because type erausre) or a `KClass` reference (won't work because I need a reified typearg)?

The thing is that as far as I know, the only way to decode a generic JSON to a serializable target class is to use `Json.decodeFromString<T>(content)`, where `T` is the target type and `content` is the JSON string. Now, `T` is defined to be reified (so that the type can be processed at runtime) and can only be filled with another reified typearg or an actual class reference. I can't use another reified typearg because I am in the context of a class and a class cannot have reified typeargs. I can also not use an actual class reference because the user of the class should be able to construct it with different targets, e.g. they decide what the target is, not me.

So, how do I do this with kotlinx.serialization? Is it even possible?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what's the problem with using `KClass` like you're showing in your constructor (which also I think should be `KClass<T>`).

Comment: According to my own knowledge, kotlinx.serialization does not take `KClass`es because it is a multiplatform library and since reflection is only available on the JVM, it can as well not use reflection. If it would work with `KClass`, I'd use it. Therefore, if it is possible, please correct me and tell me how to do it

Comment: @user AFAIK inline classes are still experimental (although that's not a big problem), but the real problem is that I want to do more than a simple wrapper class, of course. The wrapper class in the question displays just the most simplified explanation of the problem. In reality, the class should, among other things, also do some caching. I think it's obvious that for caching, I'll need more than one field. Therefore I can't use an inline class

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok so no one answered the question yet, but I also posted this question in the r/Kotlin subreddit. [Here it is](https://www.reddit.com/r/Kotlin/comments/j37tyn/kotlinx_serialization_how_to_circumvent_reified/).

I actually got an answer there (credits to u/JakeWharton), and since you might get across this StackOverflow question because you googled the same question, you might be happy to find an answer here. So here's my try to paraphrase the answer:

So, basically, kotlinx-serialization does indeed not work with `KClass`es. But when you think about it, you only need the `KClass` to determine how to serialize it. And since that is determined at compile-time when you work with KXS, you actually just need to pass the serializer (the actual strategy defining how to serialize / deserialize your class). You can obtain a serializer for every class annotated with `@Serializable` by invoking `.serializer()` on it; the result will be of the type `KSerializer<T>`. So, instead of having

```kotlin
class Wrapper<T>(private val content: String, private val type: KClass<T>)
```

and constructing it via

```kotlin
val wrapper = Wrapper("{}", Foo::class)
```

You can do it like this:

```kotlin
class Wrapper<T>(private val content: String, private val serializer: KSerializer<T>)
```

and then construct it like this:

```kotlin
val wrapper = Wrapper("{}", Foo.serializer())
```

(supposing `Foo` is annotated with `@Serializable`)

you can then serialize and deserialize by using the `KSerializer` instead of a typearg, like this:

```kotlin
val obj: T = Json.decodeFromString(serializer, "[Your JSON String]")
val str: String = Json.encodeToString(serializer, obj)
```

And that's it! Just swap out your regular `(K)Class` approach by `KSerializer` and it'll work with KXS.